# why is the for loop going on infinitely in c

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, recursion, function-definition

my question is when I run the code the loop goes on infinitely. the expected output is to print hi 5 times then go to a new line and print 4 times the 3 and so on I cant understand what is causing the loop to go infinite.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int star(int);
int main()
{
    printf("enter number\n");
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    star(a);
    return 0;
}

int star(int m)
{

    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < m; n++)
    {
        printf("hi");
    }
    printf("\n");

    star(m - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have recursion without terminating condition.

Comment: I..e look at your code. at what point will `star` *not* call itself anymore?

Comment: how can i add a terminating condition im a beginner in c

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: You probably wanted to start `star` with something like `if (m < 0) return 0;` or guard `star(m-1);` with a `if(m > 0) star(m-1);`. That way it won't keep invoking itself once m goes negative.

Comment: @EugeneSh. im trying to print star pattern

Comment: Show an example of the desired output.

Comment: @thatotherguy i understand now i did it and now the code works thnks for your input

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to check if m > 0 somewhere in your function. In this case, the loop goes infinetely, because it doesn´t have a way to get out of recursion.

Simple fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int star(int);
int main()
{
    printf("enter number\n");
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    star(a);
    return 0;
}

int star(int m)
{

    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < m; n++)
    {
        printf("hi");
    }
    printf("\n");
    if (m > 0){
        star(m - 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand now thnku for your help

Answer (score 2):

For starters the return type of the function `star` is useless and does not make a sense. Also there is no great sense to declare the parameter as having the signed integer type `int`. It would be more logically correct to declare the parameter as having at least the unsigned integer type `unsigned int`.

So the function should be declared like

```
void star( unsigned int n );
```

The function calls infinitely itself recursively because such a call is unconditional and does not depend on the value of the parameter `m`.

```
int star(int m)
{
    //...
    star(m - 1);
   
    return 0;
}
```

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void star( unsigned int );

int main( void )
{
    printf( "Enter number: " );
    unsigned int n;

    if ( scanf( "%u", &n) == 1 ) star( n );

    return 0;
}

void star( unsigned int n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf( "hi" );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );

        if ( --n ) star( n );
    }
}
```

Pay attention to that if the function was called initially with the argument equal to 0 then the function should output nothing.

Comment: Thnks for your help now I understand it.